# how to display values from 2 arrays in paragraphs in ES6/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working with bigger arrays in React, and want the following display like this: image/name image/name image/name. I have the following the code but I don't know how I can map over the images array to so it shows it's image. Thank you

```
function showProtocolsNames() {
if (supportedVaults) {
  let arr = supportedVaults
    .map((item) => item.protocolName)
    .filter((item, index, arr) => {
      return arr.indexOf(item) == index;
    });

  let arrImages = supportedVaults
    .map((item) => item.protocolKey)
    .filter((item, index, arr) => {
      return arr.indexOf(item) == index;
    });

  let protocolsName = [...new Set(arr)];
  let protocolsImages = [...new Set(arrImages)];
  console.log(protocolsName, protocolsImages);

  return protocolsName.map((vault) => {
    return (
      <>
        {' '}
        <img
          src={getVaultIcon(vault)}
          width="42px"
          height="42px"
          style={{
            marginRight: '12px',
          }}
        />
        <p className="vaults-protocol">{vault}</p>
      </>
    );
  });
}
return null;
```

}

**Solved:** **By creating an array of the images and names together and just mapping over it like DBS suggested in comments.**

Comment: ohh, sorry! I want to show it like this: 
1 hey     2 hello   3 see ya

Comment: yes, 1 sec please

Comment: I have updated my question now. I haven't asked many questions here before. Thank you very much for helping!!

Comment: that's a whole lot better - I don't do `react` so I can't help

Comment: It seems quite odd to map `protocolName` and `protocolKey` into two separate arrays, and then presumably need to stick them back together in the `getVaultIcon` function. Wouldn't you be better off building a single structure from the beginning?

Comment: It is because I was trying to get unique set of names from an array of objects and I need the images of those names. I didn't know what to do so I created the 2 set of arrays. what and how you would have done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a much simpler solution to your problem than your current approach. For example, you could use the `supportedVaults` data immediately while mapping the image/name components, like this:

```
function showProtocolsNames() {
  // added check to ensure there is data inside supportedVaults
  if (supportedVaults.length) {
    // removed the two mapped arrays

    // added index which is generated by map function
    return protocolsName.map((vault, index) => {
      // added div instead of <> in order to include a key, which is required in a map function
      return (
        <div key={`${index}-${vault?.protocolKey}`}>
          {" "}
          <img
            src={getVaultIcon(vault?.protocolKey)} // here we pass protocolKey to the getVaultIcon function
            width="42px"
            height="42px"
            style={{
              marginRight: "12px",
            }}
          />
          {/* here we add protocolName inside the paragraph */}
          <p className="vaults-protocol">{vault?.protocolName}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return null;
}
```

This logic above is based on your description of the issue, assuming `protocolKey` is what you need to pass to get the vault icon in `getVaultIcon` function and `protocolName` is the value you need to show as the name. If my perception is wrong, please edit your question to reflect more info on what exact data you need to get from the `supportedVaults` array, or what format `supportedVaults` has.

Comment: Hi there! this helped me to be directed to my answer, so thank you very much.

Comment: @Alexandria I'm glad it helped, if this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it as the answer for your post, otherwise suggest any changes or edits to it, so other people who encouraged the same problem can get the correct answer as quickly as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I will start asking better questions on here and doing better. Thnak you very much for your time and effort to answer.